# Multi Tarea en Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Como puedo hacer múltiples tareas en arduino sin utilizar la función `delay()`
y que cada tarea se ejecute durante un periodo determinado y las tareas de puede ejecutar en paralelo.

```
void setup() {
    //TODO: ...
}

void loop() {
    task1();
    delay (...);
    task2();
    delay (...);

    ...

    taskN();
    delay (...);
}
```

Comment: No veo la necesidad de usar `delay`, ¿si los eliminas hay algun problema?

Comment: Es que necesito que cada tarea se ejecute durante un tiempo determinado

Comment: ¿qué significa *se ejecute durante un tiempo determinado*?, considera que no conozco tu aplicación, ¿has revisado usar timers e interrupciones?, tu pregunta es poco clara y quizas sea un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy)

Comment: Luis Tenés que ser más específico. Como eyllasnesc te lo indica puede ser un "problema XY". Dinos cual es *tu problema y lo que has intentado*; no *el problema con lo que has intentado*

Comment: Ya Encontré Una Solución

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estuve consultando en libros y encontré esta solución que me funciona perfectamente

```
void setup() {
    //TODO: ...
}

void loop() {
    task1();
    task2();
    task3();
}


void  task1() {
    //{period}: Periodo de Tiempo en el cual se va a ejecutar esta tarea
    unsigned long period=200; //En Milisegundos

    static unsigned long previousMillis=0;

    if((millis()-previousMillis)>period){
        // ---------------------------------
        // TODO:
        // Codigo de la Tarea 
        // ...
        // ---------------------------------
        previousMillis += period;
    }  
}

void  task2() {
    //{period}: Periodo de Tiempo en el cual se va a ejecutar esta tarea
    unsigned long period=500; //En Milisegundos

    static unsigned long previousMillis=0;

    if((millis()-previousMillis)>period){
        // ---------------------------------
        // TODO:
        // Codigo de la Tarea 
        // ...
        // ---------------------------------
        previousMillis += period;
    }  
}

void  task3() {
    //{period}: Periodo de Tiempo en el cual se va a ejecutar esta tarea
    unsigned long period=1000; //En Milisegundos

    static unsigned long previousMillis=0;

    if((millis()-previousMillis)>period){
        // ---------------------------------
        // TODO:
        // Codigo de la Tarea 
        // ...
        // ---------------------------------
        previousMillis += period;
     }  
 }
```

Cada una de las tarea tiene una variable `period` que indica el periodo en el cual se va a ejecutar esta tarea este periodo esta en *Milisegundos*.

hay otra variable `estatica` llamada `previousMillis` que es la que va actuar como contador para que la tarea se ejecute en el periodo descrito.

**Referencia:**
[Medium - (Multitasking) Múltiples Tareas en Arduino sin usar la función delay()](https://medium.com/@LuisMBaezCo/multitasking-m%C3%BAltiples-tareas-en-arduino-sin-usar-la-funci%C3%B3n-delay-cea63304b17c)